# Links doesn't work in layered divs

Tags: css, html, hyperlink, anchor, layer

I've been trying to figure out how to get my links working in layered divs

**I have a big div containing two other divs:**

- main div with content and
- a navigation div for my menu

The problem is that the `main div` is overlapping the navigation div wherein i want my links to be (ribbons) so that it looks like they are being pulled out when hovered. But they arent active links at all? my css is as follow:

```
    .navigate {
    width: 1020px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    top: 190px;
    z-index: -1;
    border: 1px solid red;}
```

and

```
.main {
background: url("../images/papir.png") no-repeat center; /* papir.png bredde=1020px */ 
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 150px;
margin-bottom: 7em;
width: 1020px; /* 1020px */
height: 752px; /* 752px */ 
z-index: 0;
border: 1px solid green; }
```

it's like the `navigation div` is behind something :$

When i change the `z-index` to 0 in the `navigation div` it works just fine except that the div is not behind the `main div`..

I've tried to fix it with

```
body {
position: relative;
z-index: 0; }
```

read somewhere that it should fix the problem - but not for me

**Any ideas how to fix it?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't tell from you HTML , but make the z-index of the one you want on top higher, and if there is a div on top of the link , you can not click through a div - if that is what you were trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you have the `.navigate` div z-index set to -1 so it is behind the `.main` div. Make it greater than the other divs so it's on top. E.g. `z-index: 101;`

Comment: http://img222.imageshack.us/img222/7905/skrmbillede20120926kl02.png that's my example

the red is the navigation, the green the main and the blue is the container. I want to make the ribbon a link and when hovered looks like being pulled out a bit (a:link margin-top: 20px; a:hover margin-top: 10px;) or something like that

Comment: In that case, why make it harder than it needs to be. Make a transparent image, let's say 50px by 200px. The whole image is the ribbon, but there is let's say 50px gap up top (so the ribbon is only 150px tall of the 200px) make your a tag display:block; height: 100px; width:50px; overflow:hidden; background:url(../images/ribbon.png) 0 0 no-repeat; then on a:hover move the background position up 50-100px so it "comes out of the book a little."  e.g. a:hover {background-position:0 -75px;}

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean with transparent image? I've fixed my problem by adding

    position: relative;

to the .main-div and managed to make the pull-out effect by declaring the anchor tag as a block element:

    display: inline-block;

Comment: But you were right about adding a higher z-value. a negative z-value won't make the links active for some reason

Comment: By transparent image I mean an image with a transparent background. Such as ribbon.png - the ribbon image would have a transparent background and you could do what I suggested in the comments above based on that image and that image size. I just used 200px by 50px as an example.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working!

Just added:

```
position: relative;
```

to the .main-div

Answer (score 0):

> When i change the z-index to 0 in the navigation div it works just fine except that the div is not behind the main div..

If I understand this correctly , there is no way to get a link to work if there is another div overlapping on top of the link , ex.  If The nav div is under the main div the links on Nav div will not work

but..

if you want the div with the links on top - poistion them relative or absolute or fixed , and set the z-index to any number higher then the div you want behind

Comment: Correct, unless you use something like click mapping or `pointer-events: none;` (do a google search, 99/100 times it's not worth the effort) (and sometimes considered black hat)

Comment: http://img222.imageshack.us/img222/7905/skrmbillede20120926kl02.png that's my example

the red is the navigation, the green the main and the blue is the container. I want to make the ribbon a link and when hovered looks like being pulled out a bit (a:link margin-top: 20px; a:hover margin-top: 10px;) or something like that

Comment: @user1698771 - show an example with HTML , the actual site , or set it up on jsFiddle and I can fix it for you

Comment: Thanks @Xhynk! I had no idea about pointer-events: none;. This worked perfectly for my use case which involves a div over a canvas.

Answer (score 0):

use negative margin for the div you want to over lay for example

```
.overlay-div{margin-top:-20px;}
```